# Removing PCR Duplicates From Fastq File Containing Unique Molecular Identifiers

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to edit a Fastq file containing genomic data and Unique Molecular Identifiers flanking each sequence.

An example of the first two reads are shown below:

```
1 @HISEQ:230:C6G45ANXX:3:1101:1395:2141 1:N:0:ACAGTGGTTGAACCTT
2 TGACGGCACTTTCTCTTCCCAACCACGTGGCTGCAGACTTCTTGCTCTCAAGTTGTCCTGACATGCTCTGAGAGCACACACAACATACATACAACACCTGGATCTGTGAATTAATTACTGCCTAGG
3 +
4 BB//<<BFBFFF<FFFFBBB<<<F/FBBB<FF/B<FFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFBFB/FBFFB//F//B<FFF</</BF<BBBFFFFF//B<FBFF/77F/B/BF7/FF/<BF/7FFFFBBF//B7B
5 @HISEQ:230:C6G45ANXX:3:1101:1498:2162 1:N:0:ACAGTGGTTGAACCTT
6 TGACGGCACTTTCTCTTCCCAACCACGTGGCTGCAGACTTCTTGCTCTCAAGTTGTCCTGACATGCTCTGAGAGCACACACAACATACATACAACACCTGGATCTGTGAATTAATTACTGCCTAGG
7 +
8 BBB<B<F<FFFFFFFBFFFFFFBFFFFBFF/F<FFFFBBFFFFFFFFFFBFB/BFFFFFFFFFFFBFFB/<<<FFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFF##################################
```

These lines are explained below:

```
1 Information
2 Sequence
3 +
4 Quality Scoring
5 Information
6 Sequence
7 +
8 Quality Scoring
```

I need an output file in which all exact repeats of a given sequence (and its corresponding information) have been removed. That is, I need to remove those blocks of 4 lines in which the 2nd one have already appeared in the file.

So that in the above example because the sequence matches in lines 2 and 6 the output file should contain lines 1,2,3, and 4 but not 5,6,7, and 8.

Resulting output file:

```
1 @HISEQ:230:C6G45ANXX:3:1101:1395:2141 1:N:0:ACAGTGGTTGAACCTT
2 TGACGGCACTTTCTCTTCCCAACCACGTGGCTGCAGACTTCTTGCTCTCAAGTTGTCCTGACATGCTCTGAGAGCACACACAACATACATACAACACCTGGATCTGTGAATTAATTACTGCCTAGG
3 +
4 BB//<<BFBFFF<FFFFBBB<<<F/FBBB<FF/B<FFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFBFB/FBFFB//F//B<FFF</</BF<BBBFFFFF//B<FBFF/77F/B/BF7/FF/<BF/7FFFFBBF//B7B
```

Comment: You want a four-line block removed if its third line (the one with the nucleotide sequence) matches that of the previous block, do I understand that correctly? Are the junk lines supposed to be part of the output, and if not, how do I recognize which lines are junk?

Comment: You are correct. Everything will be in these four line chunks and all four lines should be removed if the sequence part matches. The junk lines should not be included in the output and will only ever be the first three lines of the Fastq, so the starting group of four lines starts on line 4 and sequence will then be found on lines 6,10,14,18.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the perfect case in which we loop through the file twice: firstly to calculate duplicates and then to print the appropiate lines:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
          if (FNR%4==2) {
              a[$2]++
              if (a[$2]>1) b[int(FNR/4)]=1
             }
          next}
      b[int(FNR/4)]==0' file file
```

The key here is to play with the 4K+2 lines in the file and keep track of which ones have appeared so far. If they do, we store the `K` (from `4K+2`) so that in the next loop of the file we avoid those lines being on the form `4K+0/1/2/3`.

For clarity I assumed the lines in the first column are not there (I didn't know if they were added to clarify or are really there). Removing them should be trivial.

#### Test

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {if (FNR%4==2) {a[$2]++; if (a[$2]>1) b[int(FNR/4)]=1} next} b[int(FNR/4)]==0' a a
@HISEQ:230:C6G45ANXX:3:1101:1395:2141 1:N:0:ACAGTGGTTGAACCTT
TGACGGCACTTTCTCTTCCCAACCACGTGGCTGCAGACTTCTTGCTCTCAAGTTGTCCTGACATGCTCTGAGAGCACACACAACATACATACAACACCTGGATCTGTGAATTAATTACTGCCTAGG
+
BBB<B<F<FFFFFFFBFFFFFFBFFFFBFF/F<FFFFBBFFFFFFFFFFBFB/BFFFFFFFFFFFBFFB/<<<FFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFF##################################
```

Comment: This looks like what I want to do, although I don't understand the file writing and can't seem to get it to work. Do I need your last line to be something like: b[int(FNR/4)]==0' inputfile > outputfile

Comment: Nop! The redirection is done outside the `awk` expression, you say `awk '...'  file file > new_file` (no, it is not a mistake, we write `file` twice because we read it twice). See http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ for some explanation about FNR/NR and reading a file twice.

Comment: Alright this looks great and works great I did change (FNR%4==2) to (FNR%4==1). I think the way you have it, the code is checking for duplicates on line 3 not 2. But in any case this is helpful I didn't know you could do this with awk. As always fedorqui you have been really helpful.

Comment: Nice to read that :) 2%4==2, so checking 2nd lines should be `NR%4==2`... By the way, I think (haven't tested) that `b[int(FNR/4)]==0` can be written as `int(FNR/4) not in b`.

Comment: Strange, when I use FNR%4==2 I only get a single group of four lines output. But when I use FNR%4==1 I get hundreds. This is the way I figured it in my head: 0/4 = R0, 1/4 = R1, 2/4 = R2, 3/4 = R3, 4/4 = R0. No?

Comment: Maybe i see the discrepancy, is the first line referred to by 0 not 1?

Comment: Mmmm it really depends on what you have in the beginning. If lines are in groups from 4K+1 to 4K+4 or from 4K to 4K+3. Just adjust it accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're off by one line on the FASTQ order.  In your example:

```
1 Junk
2 Junk
3 Junk
4 Information        +->
5 Sequence           |     these four lines constitute a single record
6 +                  |
7 Quality Scoring    +->
9 Information
10 Sequence
11 +
```

So lines 1-3 (Junk) are actually the top 3 lines of the *previous* record, and lines 9-11 are the top 3 of the *next* record.

In any case, I'd suggest you use BioPython's SeqIO to parse your FASTQ file and de-duplicate.

> http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO

One basic way to do it would be:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqUtils.CheckSum import seguid
detected = []
unique = []
for rec in SeqIO.parse(open('inputfile.fastq', 'rU'), 'fastq'):
   cksum = seguid(rec.seq)
   if cksum not in detected:
       unique.append(rec)
       detected.append(cksum)
SeqIO.write(unique, open('deduplicated.fastq','w'), 'fastq')
```

This reads each record and computes a checksum of the sequence to store in a list.  Each subsequent record is only added to the list for output ('unique') if its sequence doesn't have a checksum already encountered.

Comment: Oh, that is much nicer. I shall have to remember this as a direction in which to point all the biologists who come here to handle fastq files with sed and awk.

Comment: Thanks for catching the error in my line identification, that saves me from a huge headache in the future. I updated the question to reflect this. And this code looks pretty good but I have a question, is this deduplicating in a similar way to Picard does it. Because the problem is that sequences that start at the same place in the genome are marked as duplicates. But in my case all of my sequences start in the exact same place of the genome.

Comment: This example is pretty basic - it doesn't care about where on the genome any sequence comes from, nor what any identifiers are, or anything else.  All it does is compare the base sequences directly (or rather, a checksum of them).  You could even skip the checksums and just compare the sequences themselves.  [Edited for clarity]