# Remove Duplicate and Surrounding Lines From Text File

Tags: bash, awk, sed

So I posted a question earlier today that might be unnecessarily complex, so here is hopefully a clearer version.

I am trying to edit a text file and remove duplicate lines and lines surrounding them. So the file looks like this for thousands of lines:

```
Info1
Blue
Info1
Info1
Info2
Red
Info2
Info2
Info3   <- Delete line above
Blue    <- Delete Duplicate
Info3   <- Delete two lines below
Info3   <- Delete two lines below
```

I want to edit or create an output file so that all duplicate lines and the info surrounding them is removed. So sample output from above would be:

```
Info1
Blue
Info1
Info1
Info2
Red
Info2
Info2
```

As requested here is what I have started to try:

```
#Iterates through multiple files
for f in /dir/*; do
     mv "$f" "$f~" &&
     #unzip and set 2nd line and every fourth line to temp var
     #but then not really sure what to do after this
     gzip -cd "$f~" | sed '2~4s/ = $temp' | gzip > "$f"
 done
```

Comment: I suggest a look at the Linux [unique](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/uniq-command-examples/). At least you've tried something and put your approach here.

Comment: Buddy, this is Shell, not Python!

Comment: Yeah i didn't know if someone knew a way to code this in python. But also I have looked at uniq and I this does look like it might do exactly what I wanted but I dont know how to also delete the surrounding lines when uniq deletes the duplicate lines.

Comment: Instead of posting another question, you'd better clarify the first one!

Comment: Yeah I figured I just wasn't sure if I should edit the post so heavily to make it look like this one of if that was poor conduct.

Comment: Your description and sample output don't match. If you were removing duplicates and the lines around them you would have a list of unique strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing fancy, but I think it should work, assuming the data begins with and holds the structure of one line before and two-lines after the line that needs to be checked for duplicates:

```
$ cat brg.txt
Info1
Blue
Info1
Info1
Info2
Red
Info2
Info2
Info3
Blue
Info3
Info3
Info4
Green
Info4
Info4

$ cat brg.awk
NR % 4 == 1 { save = $0 }
NR % 4 == 2 && $0 in seen { flag = 0 }
NR % 4 == 2 && !($0 in seen) { flag = 1; seen[$0]; print save; print }
NR % 4 == 3 && flag
NR % 4 == 0 && flag

$ awk -f brg.awk brg.txt
Info1
Blue
Info1
Info1
Info2
Red
Info2
Info2
Info4
Green
Info4
Info4
```

Comment: Probably better to read the file twice. Look for example what I posted to the previous, related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29480682/1983854